# Complex Validation Prior to Insert

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm looking for some feedback. I need to pull a large set of data from an interface table, validate this data, and then merge it into a core table. The validation is fairly complex and fairly involved, requiring checking data against a number of different tables and against a number of scenarios.

For business reasons, this interface table is consistently being written by an external process. The current process does a pass a validation pass over portions of the data, flagging any records that fail validation in the interface table itself. We've found that, due to contention, this process scales extremely poorly... to the point where resource-wait timeouts are common. So, we need to rethink the approach of updating records in-place on the interface table.

I'm considering two different methods of doing this (I am open to alternatives). Throughput performance is the most important consideration, as we need this process to be able to keep pace with the data coming in. What would be the faster approach?

a) Pull the dataset into a cursor. Loop through each row, validating each record individually. If the record passes validation, perform the merge into the core table.

b) Pull the dataset into a temp table. Make multiple passes over the data in the temp table using SQL UPDATE statements to flag records that fail validation. Merge the data in the temp table that doesn't get flagged into the core table.

Or is there something else I've not considered?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is a far too broad for StackOverflow, but let's see if you can narrow it. I'm working on a legacy system that is essentially using the same pattern (option A in your question) but our data volumes are very modest. Could you please address at least the following topics by editing you question:

Comment: Tell more about data volumes and peaks. Are the writers or readers the problem ? Have you profiled them ? Describe the processing flow in more details. E.g. 1. several writers insert data (no updates) 2. only one reader reads previously unprocessed rows and makes some validation. 3. reader flags (update) interface rows (you've some kind of processing flag in the interface able ?) 4. data is processed and merged to a core table. What resources are exhausted ?